# User Control Properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Can I build a control that basically acts "like a MasterPage"?

What I mean to do is, say I have a grid like this in a number of pages:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="AnnouncementsPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="AnnoucementsGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Id" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Created" HeaderText="Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Modified" HeaderText="Last Modified" />
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Process" CommandName="Process" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I'd like to build a control that handles *most* of the codebehind, but I need to declare the columns for the grid declaratively in each case.

---

Is there a way to create a control like this?

```
<uc:CrudGrid ID="AnnouncementsCrud" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Created" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Modified" HeaderText="Last Modified" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Process" CommandName="Process" />
    </Columns>
</uc:CrudGrid>
```

---

or event better:

```
<uc:CrudGrid ID="AnnouncementsCrud" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Created" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Modified" HeaderText="Last Modified" />
    </Columns>
</uc:CrudGrid>
```

Maybe having to name the tag "Fields", but being able to drop the button, so it can be used in the UC's code-behind?

A lot of love to whoever has a positive answer on this <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the exact solution I was looking for:

```
    [DefaultValue((string)null)]
    [Editor(typeof(System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.DataControlFieldTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public DataControlFieldCollection Columns
    {
        get { return Grid.Columns; }
    }
```

this way I can expose the Columns from the grid in my own user control and edit the fields from the markup, keeping general functionalities within my UC

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how positive you want it to be :-)  You can always build your own control to do this.  That is one option.

Another option is to create a helper object that attaches to the grid, and keep each grid separate.

Third option is to create a user control with the common code, and programmably add columns to the grid through the user control.

HTH.

Comment: What I want is a user control with the shared functionalities, but since basically the only thing that changes is the columns I display, I want to be able to set those from the declaration of the user control, instead of inside the user control.

Comment: You could try to expose, from the user control, the DataControlFieldCollection collection, which is what the columns are made up of I believe, and then you'd have to copy them from uc to grid... haven't tried it, might work, but if it doesn't, the only way to change columns easily would be programmably creating the columns.

Comment: what do you mean by programmably creating the columns? creating them server-side and not in the markup? I'd like to avoid doing that